# any better approach to solve a nonlinear programming with a nearly convex structure?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I have a nonlinear programming problem as \begin{align}\min_x \quad&  x^TQx\nonumber\\
\text{s.t.}~~~~&f(g(x))\leq b\nonumber\\
& x\geq 0\end{align}
Here $x$ is a vector, $Q$ is a positive semidefinite. $f$ is a quadratic function over  $g(x)$. $g(x)$ is a scalar nonlinear function. For example, $g(x)=x_1^3+\sqrt{x_2}$ with $x_1$ the first element of $x$, and $x_2$ is the second element. $f(g(x))=g(x)^2.$

The problem is a non-convex nonlinear programming. Generally, many existing nonlinear programming methods can be adopted here.

I intend to seek some simpler methods which can be applied to this type of problem. Considering that, if $g$ is linear, the problem is convex. Can we just linearize $g(x)$ at each iteration? If yes, how to guarantee the convergence?

I do not know much about optimization, could anyone provide me some suggestions or relevant materials? Thanks!

Comment: "$f(x)$ is a quadratic function over $g(x)$." How? $f(x) = g^2(x)$ or $f(x) = g^2(x) + cg(x)$?

Comment: @AlexSilva From context it appears to me that $f$ is a quadratic function, i.e. $f(x) = x^TAx + c^Tx ( + d)$ cf. OP paragraph 3: "Considering that if $g$ is linear the problem is convex".

Comment: @AlexR, Are you sure that $f$ is a multivariate function? If it is, $g(x)$ cannot be a scalar function on $x$.  It is not clear to me.

Comment: @Alex Silva  Let's take a simple case as an exmple, $g(x)=x_1^3$, then $f(g(x))=(g(x)+c)^2=(x_1^3+c)^2$.

Comment: @Alex Silva please assume the functions are of proper dimension.

Comment: @lulu, you should be more specfic. How $f$ depends on $g$? What  are the map of $f$ and $g$? Just say "assume the functions are of proper dimension" makes the range of formulations for this problem very broad.

Comment: @Alex Silva  Thanks for the reminder. I edit the question and give an example of $f$ and $g$. In my problem, if you linearize $g$, the entire problem is convex. My key concern is that if it reasonable to linearize $g$ first, then solve the convex problem. With the derived solution, do the linearization again and iterate on and on until the solution converges.

Comment: @Alex Silva I guess the idea is a little similar to the so-called successive convex optimization, but I'm not sure. I do not know much about this.

Comment: The problem of this approach  is the starting point. If it is far from the solution then the linearization of $g(x)$ will be very bad. Moreover,  there is no guarantee that the iterations converge to some point (it can even move away from the solution). I suggest you  try with a simple example.

Comment: @Alex Silva  I see. Thanks a lot for your kind reply.

Answer (score 0):

@lulu, I have an idea to find at least a local solution of this problem. There is no convergence guarantees but I think it is a better approach than the linearization of $g(x)$ (which may introduce errors when the linearization is around a point far from the solution).

The idea is to solve the problem alternately. Assuming that $g(x)$ is a continuous function, the steps are the following:

**(1)** Solve the convex optimization problem

\begin{align}\min_{x_k} \quad&  x_k^TQx_k\nonumber\\
\text{s.t.}~~~~
& x_k\geq 0.\end{align}

**(2)** Test if $-\sqrt{b} \leq g(x_k) \leq \sqrt{b} $. If it is, the problem is solved. Otherwise, go to the next step.

**(3)** On one hand, if  $g(x_k) < -\sqrt{b}$, find $x_{k+1}$ closest to $x_{k}$ such that $g(x_{k+1}) = -\sqrt{b}$. 
On the other hand, if $g(x_k) > \sqrt{b}$, then find $x_{k+1}$ closest to $x_{k}$ such that $g(x_{k+1}) = \sqrt{b}$.

**(4)** Solve the convex optimization problem

\begin{align}\min_{x_{k+2}} \quad&  x_{k+1}^TQx_{k+2} + \mu\|x_{k+2}- x_{k+1}\|^2 \nonumber\\
\text{s.t.}~~~~
& x_{k+2}\geq 0,\end{align}
for some regularization factor $\mu$.

**(4)** Go to the step **(2)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The algorithm is nice. One problem is that in each iteration, the nonlinear equality has to be solved, I am not sure the computation complexity can be reduced or not.

Comment: another problem is that the solution in the third step may not be unique. (I notice that we should select the solution $x_{k+1}$ nearest to $x_{k}$, but there is still some possibility that the solution is not unique. ) If this is the case, how to conduct the fourth step?

Comment: You should have some information about $g(x)$, otherwise the problem is very hard to solve. I have supposed that $g(x) = cte$ can be solved by some inexpensive-computational  method, but it is true that if it is a complicated function, the complexity of the problem can be compromised. If you find more than one solution at some iteration, pick randomily one of them. For next iterations, it is expected in general that it does not happen often.

Comment: May I know what is 'cte' short for? By the way, it seems there is a typo in the fourth step. I guess the objective function should be $x_{k+2}^TQx_{k+2}$, instead of $x_{k+1}^TQx_{k+2}$. Right?

Comment: 1) cte = constant. 2) No, it is not a typo, but $x^{T}_{k+2}Qx_{k+2}$ can be another option. I prefer $x^{T}_{k+1}Qx_{k+2}$ because is a linear term. You can test both.